# Inline animation-delay works for Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm playing with some css transitions and setting a different animation-delay for dynamic elements so the css animations are staggered on the page.

Here is the animation

```
-webkit-animation: bounceInLeft .5s ease-in 0s backwards;
-moz-animation: bounceInLeft .5s ease-in 0s backwards;
 animation: bounceInLeft .5s ease-in 0s backwards;
```

The actual animation is working fine on both ff and chrome but on firefox the animations are correctly delayed in intervals whereas on chrome all the animations happen instantly.

Here is the inline code. This works correctly on firefox

```
style="animation-delay: 1s;"
```

This does not work on chrome

```
style="-webkit-animation-delay: 1s;"
```

I have specified a delay in the animation rule but I thought that placing one inline would override it, which it does on firefox. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created a jsfiddle replicating you situation and it seems to be honoring the inline delay in chrome for me. Perhaps there is an issue elsewhere. Check out this fiddle, maybe it will help illuminate a separate issue. http://jsfiddle.net/vFKuu/

**HTML**

```
<div id="some-div" style="animation-delay: 1s; -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; -moz-animation-delay: 1s; -o-animation-delay: 1s;">Hi</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
#some-div
{
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background:#f00;
    font-family:Arial;
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation .5s ease-in 0s backwards;
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation .5s ease-in 0s backwards;
    -o-animation: cssAnimation .5s ease-in 0s backwards;
    animation: cssAnimation .5s ease-in 0s backwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    from { transform: translate(50px); }
    to { transform:  translate(0px); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    from { -webkit-transform: translate(50px); }
    to { -webkit-transform:  translate(0px); }
}
@-moz-keyframes cssAnimation {
    from { -moz-transform:translate(50px); }
    to { -moz-transform: translate(0px); }
}
@-o-keyframes cssAnimation
{
    from { -o-transform: translate(50px); }
    to { -o-transform:  translate(0px); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found something weird. For some reason the only way the inline would override the style rule in chrome is if the animation-delay is a value that is **not** 0.

It works fine in firefox if the value is 0 just not chrome. I fixed it by changing the initial value of the delay to 1s then overriding it using inline styles.